# Adding Facebook page tab using JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In the Facebook SDK (JavaScript), the API to add page tab to a page:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
"/{page-id}/tabs",
"POST",
{
    "object": {
        "app_id": "{app-id}"
    }
},
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

I have tried this API call as it is, but it doesn't work, an error message said:

> (#100) One and only one of params 'tab' or 'app_id' must be provided

Answer (score 0):

I think that's obvious you just have to provide one of the parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
"/{page-id}/tabs",
"POST",
{
        "app_id": "{app-id}"
    },
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

passed as this way.